# Why does `pip install elsie` fail?

Tags: python, pip, lxml

First I create a folder:

```bash
mkdir try_elsie
```

Go into folder:

```bash
cd try_elsie
```

Next I create a virtual environment:

```bash
python -m venv venv
```

Then I update pip:

```bash
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then I try to install Elsie:

```bash
pip install elsie
```

This produces the error:

```bash
Collecting elsie
  Using cached elsie-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting Pillow<9.1.0,>=9.0.0
  Using cached Pillow-9.0.1.tar.gz (49.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting lxml<4.7,>=4.6
  Using cached lxml-4.6.5.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting marko==1.2.0
  Using cached marko-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting pygments<2.12,>=2.11
  Using cached Pygments-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting pypdf2<1.27,>=1.26
  Using cached PyPDF2-1.26.0.tar.gz (77 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: pypdf2, pygments, Pillow, marko, lxml, elsie
  DEPRECATION: pypdf2 is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for pypdf2 ... done
  DEPRECATION: Pillow is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for Pillow ... done
  DEPRECATION: lxml is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [252 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.6.5.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against libxml2 2.11.4 and libxslt 1.1.38
      running install
      /home/galen/projects/try_elsie/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/html
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml
      copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/lxml
      gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python/src=/usr/src/debug/python -flto=auto -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/home/galen/projects/try_elsie/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/src/lxml/etree.o -w
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyErr_GetTopmostException’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:261877:21: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      261877 |     while ((exc_info->exc_type == NULL || exc_info->exc_type == Py_None) &&
             |                     ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:261877:51: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      261877 |     while ((exc_info->exc_type == NULL || exc_info->exc_type == Py_None) &&
             |                                                   ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSave’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:261891:21: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      261891 |     *type = exc_info->exc_type;
             |                     ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:261893:19: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      261893 |     *tb = exc_info->exc_traceback;
             |                   ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionReset’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:261907:24: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      261907 |     tmp_type = exc_info->exc_type;
             |                        ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:261909:22: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      261909 |     tmp_tb = exc_info->exc_traceback;
             |                      ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:261910:13: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      261910 |     exc_info->exc_type = type;
             |             ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:261912:13: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      261912 |     exc_info->exc_traceback = tb;
             |             ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__GetException’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:261994:28: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      261994 |         tmp_type = exc_info->exc_type;
             |                            ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:261996:26: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      261996 |         tmp_tb = exc_info->exc_traceback;
             |                          ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:261997:17: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      261997 |         exc_info->exc_type = local_type;
             |                 ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:261999:17: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      261999 |         exc_info->exc_traceback = local_tb;
             |                 ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ExceptionSwap’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:262185:24: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      262185 |     tmp_type = exc_info->exc_type;
             |                        ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:262187:22: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      262187 |     tmp_tb = exc_info->exc_traceback;
             |                      ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:262188:13: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      262188 |     exc_info->exc_type = *type;
             |             ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:262190:13: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      262190 |     exc_info->exc_traceback = *tb;
             |             ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_Coroutine_ExceptionClear’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:264391:18: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      264391 |     t = exc_state->exc_type;
             |                  ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264393:19: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      264393 |     tb = exc_state->exc_traceback;
             |                   ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264394:14: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      264394 |     exc_state->exc_type = NULL;
             |              ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264396:14: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      264396 |     exc_state->exc_traceback = NULL;
             |              ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_Coroutine_SendEx’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:264473:18: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      264473 |     if (exc_state->exc_type) {
             |                  ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264476:22: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      264476 |         if (exc_state->exc_traceback) {
             |                      ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264477:68: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      264477 |             PyTracebackObject *tb = (PyTracebackObject *) exc_state->exc_traceback;
             |                                                                    ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264481:14: error: invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘PyFrameObject’ {aka ‘struct _frame’}
      264481 |             f->f_back = PyThreadState_GetFrame(tstate);
             |              ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_Coroutine_ResetFrameBackpointer’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:264512:33: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      264512 |     PyObject *exc_tb = exc_state->exc_traceback;
             |                                 ^~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.11/Python.h:38,
                       from src/lxml/etree.c:96:
      src/lxml/etree.c:264518:19: error: invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘PyFrameObject’ {aka ‘struct _frame’}
      264518 |         Py_CLEAR(f->f_back);
             |                   ^~
      /usr/include/python3.11/pyport.h:24:38: note: in definition of macro ‘_Py_CAST’
         24 | #define _Py_CAST(type, expr) ((type)(expr))
            |                                      ^~~~
      /usr/include/python3.11/object.h:581:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘_PyObject_CAST’
        581 |         PyObject *_py_tmp = _PyObject_CAST(op); \
            |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264518:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
      264518 |         Py_CLEAR(f->f_back);
             |         ^~~~~~~~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.11/Python.h:44:
      src/lxml/etree.c:264518:19: error: invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘PyFrameObject’ {aka ‘struct _frame’}
      264518 |         Py_CLEAR(f->f_back);
             |                   ^~
      /usr/include/python3.11/object.h:583:14: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_CLEAR’
        583 |             (op) = NULL;                        \
            |              ^~
      In file included from /usr/include/python3.11/Python.h:45:
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_Coroutine_traverse_excstate’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:264824:23: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      264824 |     Py_VISIT(exc_state->exc_type);
             |                       ^~
      /usr/include/python3.11/objimpl.h:199:13: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_VISIT’
        199 |         if (op) {                                                       \
            |             ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264824:23: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      264824 |     Py_VISIT(exc_state->exc_type);
             |                       ^~
      /usr/include/python3.11/pyport.h:24:38: note: in definition of macro ‘_Py_CAST’
         24 | #define _Py_CAST(type, expr) ((type)(expr))
            |                                      ^~~~
      /usr/include/python3.11/objimpl.h:200:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘_PyObject_CAST’
        200 |             int vret = visit(_PyObject_CAST(op), arg);                  \
            |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264824:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘Py_VISIT’
      264824 |     Py_VISIT(exc_state->exc_type);
             |     ^~~~~~~~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264826:23: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      264826 |     Py_VISIT(exc_state->exc_traceback);
             |                       ^~
      /usr/include/python3.11/objimpl.h:199:13: note: in definition of macro ‘Py_VISIT’
        199 |         if (op) {                                                       \
            |             ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264826:23: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      264826 |     Py_VISIT(exc_state->exc_traceback);
             |                       ^~
      /usr/include/python3.11/pyport.h:24:38: note: in definition of macro ‘_Py_CAST’
         24 | #define _Py_CAST(type, expr) ((type)(expr))
            |                                      ^~~~
      /usr/include/python3.11/objimpl.h:200:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘_PyObject_CAST’
        200 |             int vret = visit(_PyObject_CAST(op), arg);                  \
            |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      src/lxml/etree.c:264826:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘Py_VISIT’
      264826 |     Py_VISIT(exc_state->exc_traceback);
             |     ^~~~~~~~
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__Coroutine_NewInit’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:265073:22: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      265073 |     gen->gi_exc_state.exc_type = NULL;
             |                      ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:265075:22: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’
      265075 |     gen->gi_exc_state.exc_traceback = NULL;
             |                      ^
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx__ReturnWithStopIteration’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:266058:32: error: ‘_PyErr_StackItem’ {aka ‘struct _err_stackitem’} has no member named ‘exc_type’
      266058 |     if (!__pyx_tstate->exc_info->exc_type)
             |                                ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_AddTraceback’:
      src/lxml/etree.c:522:62: error: invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘PyFrameObject’ {aka ‘struct _frame’}
        522 |   #define __Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber(frame, lineno)  (frame)->f_lineno = (lineno)
            |                                                              ^~
      src/lxml/etree.c:267283:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘__Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber’
      267283 |     __Pyx_PyFrame_SetLineNumber(py_frame, py_line);
             |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      creating tmp
      cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitdq3mqvxo.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitdq3mqvxo.o
      /tmp/xmlXPathInitdq3mqvxo.c: In function ‘main’:
      /tmp/xmlXPathInitdq3mqvxo.c:3:5: warning: ‘xmlXPathInit’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          3 |     xmlXPathInit();
            |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /tmp/xmlXPathInitdq3mqvxo.c:1:
      /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xpath.h:564:21: note: declared here
        564 |                     xmlXPathInit                (void);
            |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      cc tmp/xmlXPathInitdq3mqvxo.o -lxml2 -o a.out
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I thought that

```bash
× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml
```

suggested that I should separately install `lxml`.

So I tried installing `lxml`

```bash
pip install lxml
```

and confirmation of installation.

```bash
Collecting lxml
  Obtaining dependency information for lxml from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/62/ffc30348ae141f69f9f23b65ba769db7ca209856c9a9b3406279e0ea24de/lxml-4.9.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached lxml-4.9.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Using cached lxml-4.9.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (7.9 MB)
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-4.9.3
```

So then I went back to install Elsie again:

```bash
pip install elsie
```

which resulted in a similar error (if not identical). I have not included it since SO limits character length. Hopefully my example should be reproducible with my system and Python info:

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux orcus 6.4.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 03 Aug 2023 16:02:01 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ python --version
Python 3.11.3

$ pip --version
pip 23.2.1 from /home/galen/projects/try_elsie/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

I can see from the output that something is going wrong with the building of the `lxml` extension...

What is going wrong? Is there a maintainable fix such that Elsie installs?

Comment: I think `elsie` is pulling a version of lxml too old for python 3.11. You can try an older python version using `pyenv`.

Comment: @jordanm Yes, that seems to be it. Please post as an answer if you want credit.